# Seamless video loop in gstreamer

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to loop the video playback using gstreamer and it's python bindings.  First attempt was to hook EOS *message* and generate seek message for the pipeline:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst

import time

if not Gst.init_check()[0]:
    print("gstreamer initialization failed")

source0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "source0")
assert source0 is not None
source0.set_property("location", "video0.mp4")

qtdemux0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("qtdemux", "demux0")
assert qtdemux0 is not None

decoder0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nxvideodec", "video_decoder0")
assert decoder0 is not None

def demux0_pad_added(demux, pad):
    if pad.name == 'video_0':  # We expect exactly first one video stream
        pad.link(decoder0.get_static_pad("sink"))

qtdemux0.connect("pad-added", demux0_pad_added)

video_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nxvideosink", "video_sink")
assert video_sink is not None

pipeline0 = Gst.Pipeline()
assert pipeline0 is not None
pipeline0.add(source0)
pipeline0.add(qtdemux0)
pipeline0.add(decoder0)
pipeline0.add(video_sink)

source0.link(qtdemux0)
"""qtdemux0 -> decoder0 dynamic linking"""
decoder0.link(video_sink)

######################################################

def main():
    message_bus = pipeline0.get_bus()
    pipeline0.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    while True:
        if message_bus.have_pending():  # Working without glib mainloop
            message = message_bus.pop()
            if message.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:  # End-Of-Stream: loop the video, seek to beginning
                pipeline0.seek(1.0,
                              Gst.Format.TIME,
                              Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH,
                              Gst.SeekType.SET, 0,
                              Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)
            elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
                print("ERROR", message)
                break
        time.sleep(0.01) # Tried 0.001 - same result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And it actually works quite fine except one thing - seek to the beginning is not really seamless. I can see tiny glitch. Because the video is an infinite animation this tiny glitch actually become noticeable. My second attempt was to use queue for decoded frames and hook EOS *event*:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst

import time

if not Gst.init_check()[0]:
    print("gstreamer initialization failed")

source0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "source0")
assert source0 is not None
source0.set_property("location", "video0.mp4")

qtdemux0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("qtdemux", "demux0")
assert qtdemux0 is not None

decoder0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nxvideodec", "video_decoder0")
assert decoder0 is not None

def demux0_pad_added(demux, pad):
    if pad.name == 'video_0':  # We expect exactly first one video stream
        pad.link(decoder0.get_static_pad("sink"))

qtdemux0.connect("pad-added", demux0_pad_added)

queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "queue")
assert queue is not None
video_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nxvideosink", "video_sink")
assert video_sink is not None

pipeline0 = Gst.Pipeline()
assert pipeline0 is not None
pipeline0.add(source0)
pipeline0.add(qtdemux0)
pipeline0.add(decoder0)
pipeline0.add(queue)
pipeline0.add(video_sink)

source0.link(qtdemux0)
"""qtdemux0 -> decoder0 dynamic linking"""
decoder0.link(queue)
queue.link(video_sink)

######################################################

def cb_event(pad, info, *user_data):
    event = info.get_event()
    if event is not None and event.type == Gst.EventType.EOS:
        decoder0.seek(1.0,
                      Gst.Format.TIME,
                      Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH,
                      Gst.SeekType.SET, 0,
                      Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)
        return Gst.PadProbeReturn.DROP
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.PASS

def main():
    dec0_src_pad = decoder0.get_static_pad("src")
    dec0_src_pad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BLOCK | Gst.PadProbeType.EVENT_DOWNSTREAM, cb_event)

    message_bus = pipeline0.get_bus()
    pipeline0.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    while True:
        # do nothing
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

After the first EOS event the playback is just stalled. I've tried several different things like: *pass* the EOS event, *drop* EOS and add offset to the decoder's source pad, send seek event to the pipeline itself and others. But I can't get it work.

In an effort to understand I also tried to enable debug mode and write my own kinda logger of pipeline activity using pad probes. Debug mode was not very useful, the log is very bulky and missing some details. My own log includes upstream/downstream events and the buffers timing information. However, I still can not understand what is wrong and how to get it to work.

Obviously I not just missing something but do not understand some fundamental thing about how gstreamer pipeline works.

**So, the question is:** What should I do with the second version of code to get it work? 
Additional question: Are there some tools or techniques to get clear idea of what is happening inside the pipeline and its contained elements?

I will very appreciate detailed answers. It is more important for me to ***understand*** what I am doing wrong than to just bring the program to work.

***p.s.*** Program is run under GNU/Linux on the NanoPi S2 board. Video is stored in the MP4 container (without audio) and compressed with h264. Please feel free to post code samples in any language, not necessarily Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, okay. I didn't get *an answer* so I continued research and finally found solution.
Below I'll show two different approaches. First - direct answer to the question with working code sample. Second - different approach, which seems to be more native for gstreamer and definitely is more simple. Both give desired result - seamless video loop.

#### Corrected code (the answer, but not the best approach)

Changes:

1. Added video duration query. Every loop we should increase time offset for a *video duration* value. It makes possible to emulate infinite contiguous stream.
2. The seek event emitting moved to a separate thread. According to [this post](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Flushing-the-data-in-partial-pipeline-tp4681893p4681899.html), we can not emit seek event from the streaming thread. Also, have a look at [this file](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-editing-services/tree/plugins/nle/nlesource.c) (link from mentioned post).
3. Event callback now drops `FLUSH` events (contiguous stream should not have a `FLUSH` events).
4. Video decoder changed from nxvideodec to avdec_h264. This is not relevant to the initial question and is done [for a very special reason](http://www.friendlyarm.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=2047).

Code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst

import time
import threading

if not Gst.init_check()[0]:
    print("gstreamer initialization failed")

source0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "source0")
assert source0 is not None
source0.set_property("location", "video0.mp4")

qtdemux0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("qtdemux", "demux0")
assert qtdemux0 is not None

decoder0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("avdec_h264", "video_decoder0")
assert decoder0 is not None

def demux0_pad_added(demux, pad):
    if pad.name == 'video_0':  # We expect exactly first one video stream
        pad.link(decoder0.get_static_pad("sink"))

qtdemux0.connect("pad-added", demux0_pad_added)

queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "queue")
assert queue is not None
video_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nxvideosink", "video_sink")
assert video_sink is not None

pipeline0 = Gst.Pipeline()
assert pipeline0 is not None
pipeline0.add(source0)
pipeline0.add(qtdemux0)
pipeline0.add(decoder0)
pipeline0.add(queue)
pipeline0.add(video_sink)

source0.link(qtdemux0)
"""qtdemux0 -> decoder0 dynamic linking"""
decoder0.link(queue)
queue.link(video_sink)

# UPD: Get video duration
pipeline0.set_state(Gst.State.PAUSED)
assert pipeline0.get_state(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE).state == Gst.State.PAUSED
duration_ok, duration = pipeline0.query_duration(Gst.Format.TIME)
assert duration_ok

######################################################

seek_requested = threading.Event()
# UPD: Seek thread. Wait for seek request from callback and generate seek event
def seek_thread_func(queue_sink_pad):
    cumulative_offset = 0
    while True:
        seek_requested.wait()
        seek_requested.clear()
        decoder0.seek(1.0,
                      Gst.Format.TIME,
                      Gst.SeekFlags.FLUSH,
                      Gst.SeekType.SET, 0,
                      Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)
        # Add offset. It is important step to ensure that downstream elements will 'see' infinite contiguous stream
        cumulative_offset += duration
        queue_sink_pad.set_offset(cumulative_offset)

def cb_event(pad, info):
    event = info.get_event()
    if event is not None:
        if event.type == Gst.EventType.EOS:  # UPD: Set 'seek_requested' flag
            seek_requested.set()
            return Gst.PadProbeReturn.DROP
        elif event.type == Gst.EventType.FLUSH_START or event.type == Gst.EventType.FLUSH_STOP:  # UPD: Drop FLUSH
            return Gst.PadProbeReturn.DROP
    return Gst.PadProbeReturn.OK

def main():
    queue_sink_pad = queue.get_static_pad("sink")

    # UPD: Create separate 'seek thread'
    threading.Thread(target=seek_thread_func, daemon=True, args=(queue_sink_pad,)).start()

    dec0_src_pad = decoder0.get_static_pad("src")
    dec0_src_pad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.EVENT_DOWNSTREAM | Gst.PadProbeType.EVENT_FLUSH,
                           cb_event)

    pipeline0.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

    while True:
        # do nothing
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code works. Seek is effectively performed while buffers from the queue still playing. However, I believe it can contain some flaws or even bugs. For example, `SEGMENT` events passed downstream with the `RESET` flag; it doesn't seems right. Much more clear (and probably more correct/reliable) way to implement this approach is to create a gstreamer plugin. Plugin will manage events and tune event's and buffer's timestamp.

But there is a more simple and native solution:

#### Using segment seek and `SEGMENT_DONE` message

According to the [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/design/seeking.html#seeking):

> Segment seeking (using the `GST_SEEK_FLAG_SEGMENT`) will not emit an `EOS`
>   at the end of the playback segment but will post a `SEGMENT_DONE`
>   message on the bus. This message is posted by the element driving the
>   playback in the pipeline, typically a demuxer. After receiving the
>   message, the application can reconnect the pipeline or issue other
>   seek events in the pipeline. **Since the message is posted as early as
>   possible in the pipeline, the application has some time to issue a new
>   seek to make the transition seamless.** Typically the allowed delay is
>   defined by the buffer sizes of the sinks as well as the size of any
>   queues in the pipeline.

Message `SEGMENT_DONE` indeed is posted earlier than the queue becomes empty. This gives more than enough time to perform next seek. So all we need to do is to issue segment seek in very beginning of the playback. Then wait for `SEGMENT_DONE` message and send next **non-flushing** seek event.
Here is working example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gst", "1.0")
from gi.repository import Gst

import time

if not Gst.init_check()[0]:
    print("gstreamer initialization failed")

source0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesrc", "source0")
assert source0 is not None
source0.set_property("location", "video0.mp4")

qtdemux0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("qtdemux", "demux0")
assert qtdemux0 is not None

decoder0 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nxvideodec", "video_decoder0")
assert decoder0 is not None

def demux0_pad_added(demux, pad):
    if pad.name == 'video_0':  # We expect exactly first one video stream
        pad.link(decoder0.get_static_pad("sink"))

qtdemux0.connect("pad-added", demux0_pad_added)

queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make("queue", "queue")
assert queue is not None
video_sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("nxvideosink", "video_sink")
assert video_sink is not None

pipeline0 = Gst.Pipeline()
assert pipeline0 is not None
pipeline0.add(source0)
pipeline0.add(qtdemux0)
pipeline0.add(decoder0)
pipeline0.add(queue)
pipeline0.add(video_sink)

source0.link(qtdemux0)
"""qtdemux0 -> decoder0 dynamic linking"""
decoder0.link(queue)
queue.link(video_sink)

######################################################

def main():
    message_bus = pipeline0.get_bus()
    pipeline0.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    pipeline0.get_state(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
    pipeline0.seek(1.0,
                   Gst.Format.TIME,
                   Gst.SeekFlags.SEGMENT,
                   Gst.SeekType.SET, 0,
                   Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)

    while True:
        if message_bus.have_pending():  # Working without glib mainloop
            message = message_bus.pop()
            if message.type == Gst.MessageType.SEGMENT_DONE:
                pipeline0.seek(1.0,
                              Gst.Format.TIME,
                              Gst.SeekFlags.SEGMENT,
                              Gst.SeekType.SET, 0,
                              Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)
            elif message.type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
                print("bus ERROR", message)
                break
        time.sleep(0.01)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With default queue configuration the `SEGMENT_DONE` message is posted approximately 1 second earlier than last video frame is played. Non-flushing seek ensures that none of the frames will be lost. Together this gives perfect result - truly seamless video loop.

Note: I switch pipeline to the PLAYING state and then perform initial non-flushing seek. Alternatively we can switch pipeline to the PAUSED state, perform **flushing** segment seek and then switch pipeline to the PLAYING state.

Note 2: Different sources suggests slightly different solution. See link below.

---

Related topics and sources:

1. `http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Flushing-the-data-in-partial-pipeline-tp4681893p4681899.html`

   - `https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-editing-services/tree/plugins/nle/nlesource.c`
2. http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Loop-a-file-using-playbin-without-artefacts-td4671952.html

   - http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/attachment/4671975/0/gstseamlessloop.py
   - https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/tests/icles/test-segment-seeks.c

Comment: Still work with gstreamer and today found another good [addition to this topic which I want to share](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/change-location-of-filesrc-element-without-breaking-tcpserversink-connection-tp4661248p4661273.html). Author explains what to do to simulate _live_ stream from a file. It is not directly related to this topic but definitely could be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the SEGMENT_DONE method:

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib
Gst.init(None)

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch('uridecodebin uri=file://%s name=d d. ! autovideosink d. ! autoaudiosink' %sys.argv[1])
bus = pipeline.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()

def on_segment_done(bus, msg):
    pipeline.seek(1.0,
        Gst.Format.TIME,
        Gst.SeekFlags.SEGMENT,
        Gst.SeekType.SET, 0,
        Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)
    return True
bus.connect('message::segment-done', on_segment_done)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
pipeline.get_state(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
pipeline.seek(1.0,
    Gst.Format.TIME,
    Gst.SeekFlags.SEGMENT,
    Gst.SeekType.SET, 0,
    Gst.SeekType.NONE, 0)

GLib.MainLoop().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to look at the `gst-play-1.0` application as well as the `playbin` element of GStreamer.

See here: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-base/blob/master/tools/gst-play.c

This one supports a `--gapless` option to play many files without gaps. It makes use of the `about-to-finish` signal of the `playbin` element.

This particular application does that with multiple files instead of the same, but I guess you can try giving the same file multiple times for a test if its really seamless or exhibits the same issue with your approach 1).

Basically I think that EOS is just a bit too late to get the first frame ready again in time due to deinit/init/processing of the decoder and flushing the pipeline. Also the flushing will kind of reset your stream, the pipeline goes into prerolling again and syncs to a new clock. It really is not a continuous stream from the inside.

Alternatively perhaps GStreamer Editing Services can do this too. But this probably works with multiple tracks which means it may try to instantiate multiple decoder instances at the same time to do parallel processing - which may be an issue on your board.

Last resort could be to demux the MP4 to a raw bistream, loop this bitstream continuous into a socket and decode from that. Then it will appear as an infinite bitstream that is being played back.

Edit:
Perhaps it is also worth a shot to try out `multifilesrc` with its `loop` property to see if that one operates gapless or has to perform a flush between files as well.